# How to use setStyleName in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I like to know use of setStyleName function in Google App Scripts. What I thought it was, we can define css and set it in widgets. Please provide some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Per Anton Soradoi

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apps-script/setstylename/apps-script/g518ngYdg1M/3OagCbn4c-MJ

> If you read the method description for setStylePrimaryName as well as
>   the other three you will see the following: "This is useful for
>   debugging but is otherwise of minimal use since there is no way to use
>   custom stylesheets in UiApp."
>
> For example, you can set a style name and use it as a marker to find
>   that widget in the browser with firebug.

Answer (score -2):

You can use stylesheets in the Google Apps Script UiApp, the format is slightly different from CSS, but the principle that you have a separate file to contain the formatting remain.

See my blog post at http://www.harryonline.net/scripts/stylesheets-in-google-apps-script-uiapp/494